# SSL Server Certificate for SNOM Handset local network

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, snom

Im coding for SNOM handsets

Basically I do a $post to a hashed URL as below

```
$post("https://8a4a1db6256ec8e310193a166d6d1f84@192.168.1.110/command.htm?number=01233456789")
```

Returns

```
net::ERR_CERT_INVALID
```

If I call HTTP the phone dials fine, BUT if run from app then the windows throws the security issue as AJAX call has to be secure. Tags are set to off, client is set and defined, works if I post an HTTP request .

I have created my own DER cert as well and uploaded that to the phone and I tried to register this certificate with the browser but no avail.

I have in chrome dropped down the cert and clicked it to ALWAYS TRUST but it keeps falling back to INVALID

There are several certificats on the phone just cant get a browser to trust them ?

Any advice or point of where to read up on how to register the server cert with my users browsers ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so anyone working their way through this issue there's a few steps you need to take

1 - set http client username and passwords

2 - in the phone interface ensure connection types are set to hhtp AND https

3 - set hidden tags to false

4 - set authentication scheme to DIGEST then MD5 the password int eh post

5 - Download ca.cert from http://downloads.snom.net/documentation/ca.crt

6 - install the cert on your local computer THEN set the cert to ALWAYS TRUSTED

7 - figure out a way around CORS...